# Подпись под именем. Синтаксический статус

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

На телевидении (в новостях и шоу) при представлении выступающих демонстрируется такая запись:

> Воробьев А.Ю.
> Губернатор Московской области
>
> Иванова Анна
> Участница ДТП, не признает свою вину

**Губернатор Московской области** и **Участница ДТП** - это именные сказуемые? Можно ли здесь говорить о неполном предложении? Мое мнение, что здесь спорный случай и возможны две трактовки. С одной стороны, это просто указание должности (такая конструкция предложением не является). С другой стороны, в подобных конструкциях встречается и глаголы ("не признает вину", "уверена, что муж ей изменяет"), что позволяет трактовать такую запись как неполное предложение. Выскажите, пожалуйста, свое мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Да уж, достаточно нестандартный вопрос. Постараюсь на него ответить.

Здесь, как Вы понимаете, мы имеем дело с записью в СМИ, которая, как и любая другая запись, созданная **автором**, может иметь свои собственные правила оформления, от которых и зависит, скажем, роль определённых слов и словосочетаний. Разумеется, точно установить синтаксис предложений может только сам создатель статьи, однако, ввиду невозможности данного события, попробуем разобраться самостоятельно.

На мой взгляд, в обоих случаях, как Вы уже сказали, используются неполные предложения, но и это вызывает некоторые сомнения из-за отсутствия прямого диалога между некоторыми лицами вида:

> Кто этот человек?
>
> Воробьёв А.Ю.
>
> Кто он?
>
> Губернатор Московской области.

Разберу второй пример аналогичным способом:

> Кто это?
>
> Иванова Анна.
>
> Кто она и **что она делает**?
>
> Участница ДТП, не признаёт свою вину.

Но, как мне кажется, такие конструкции вполне возможны как некоторая отдельная разновидность неполных предложений. Подобные ситуации, кстати, и в разговорной речи распространены. Я бы назвал это "ответ на ещё не заданный вопрос". Раз уж мы решили, что предложение неполное, то разберём его по этой же логике:

**Воробьёв А.Ю. Кто он *есть* (глагол-связка)? (Он) (*есть*) губернатор**. Здесь **губернатор** является именной частью СИС, необходимого для ответа на заданный (**подразумевающийся**) вопрос. Аналогично поступаем со вторым примером.

Надеюсь, помог разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что в данных вариантах **Губернатор Московской области** и **Участница ДТП** являются обособленными приложениями.

Приложение - это в некотором смысле дополнение к существительному, которое даёт “поясняющий смысл”. Приложение выполняет роль пояснения существительного.

Вот более научное определение:

> Приложение — это определение, выраженное именем существительным,
>   согласованном в роде, числе и падеже с определяемым словом.